# AWS S3 bucket 403

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to host my angular app.
But after I make my bucket publicly accessible and enable static website hosting, I still get 403 when I try to access it.
It seems like something is wrong with the bucket policy, but I'm not sure where it is wrong.
Please give me any advice. Thanks.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: **Security Advice:** This bucket policy is allowing anyone in the world to do anything with your bucket, including uploading files, download files, deleting files and deleting the bucket itself. **Never** grant `s3:*` permissions in a bucket policy. (Well, it has an error, detailed below, that prevents some of these operations, but the warning still stands.)

Answer (score 1):

**Security Advice:** The above bucket policy is allowing anyone in the world to do anything with your bucket, including uploading files, download files, deleting files and deleting the bucket itself. **Never** grant `s3:*` permissions in a bucket policy. (Well, it has an error, detailed below, that prevents some of these operations, but the warning still stands.)

As to your 403 error, some operations in Amazon S3 apply to the **bucket** itself and some operations apply to **objects**.

For example, listing the contents of a bucket requires **permissions on the bucket** itself:

```json
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]"
```

Operations on **objects** *within* the bucket require **permission at the object level**:

```json
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/*"
```

The `/*` at the end grants permission to *any object within the bucket*.

So, if you wish to make the bucket "public" such that anyone can read/download an object in the bucket *if they know the name of the object*, you could use this policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my-bucket-name]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.
I've tried the policy you pasted, but I still get 403.
And then I tried another policy as below, I get a 404.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKETNAME]/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: How are you accessing the object?

Comment: By the endpoint point provided when enabling static website hosting.

Comment: You are just putting a URL into a web browser, is that correct? And the URL looks like `http://bucket-name.s3-website-Region.amazonaws.com/foo.html`?

Comment: Yes, I am. And the URL looks like that.

Comment: Then you're doing everything right! I presume you have turned off **S3 Block Public Access**?

Comment: Yes, I do.
On the Properties page, it says "Publicly accessible".
But I still get 404